# How to send result value from class and send value to a textbox Mainform?

Tags: c#, forms, class

I have created a class in which this class calculates some values.

i would like to send the result value to my main form in a textbox.

```
class Calculations
{
    public void Calculate()
    {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;

        int resultwew = a + b;

        MainForm.ACGTB.Text = resultwew;

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem? Do you get any error Messages. What is the expected result and what is the actual result. Also I'd recommend rewriting the method to return the value and write it to the textbox from where you would call the method.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

in your `Calculations` class create a simple one like so

```
public  int resultwewProp{ get; set; }
```

then set the `resultwew` to the property we just created

```
resultwewProp = resultwew
```

and then in your other class you can call it like so

```
Calculations calcs = new Calculations();    
int result = calcs.resultwewProp;
```

Comment: Why not just return the value in for the method?

Comment: @sLowDowN also an option